# Is there a difference between Sarnu and Sararnu?

Tags: words, viduy-confession

In the vidui, we list our sins alphabetically, and for the samech, the word in my machzor is "sararnu" -- this is translated as "we have turned away."

After the list there is a paragraph which further discusses a consequence of (what I assumed was) all of our sins collectively, and this begins with "sarnu" -- also translated as "we have turned away."

Are the two terms simply different spellings of the same thing (and in that case, why are there two spellings) or do they refer to different types of sins, or attitudes about sin, or something else?

Textually, sar (in malachim 1, 20:43, 21:4 and 5) seems to mean "upset" while sarar (many uses) seems to be related to sor (as in ben sorer) which means to turn or stop (cf Yirmiyah 6:28, סָרֵי סוֹרְרִים , extremely perverse).

The other example of a doubled letter form I can think of quickly is mar and marar but both seem, textually, to refer to bitterness or sharpness and sadness.

Comment: You mentioned the 1st *pasuk* - the *ben sorer umoreh* - that I was going to investigate. Rash"i explains the word to mean "turns away from the proper path", and uses the word "sar" - turn away. It seems, then, that "sorer" is a special "extension" of the word "sar" specifically applied to someone who turns away from the proper path of following *mitzvot*. That's what I'm inferring from Rash"i. I'm going to have a look at your verse in Yirmiyahu. If it has the same meaning, there, I'm inclined to think there's some consistency in that extended definition.

Comment: Ahah! Look at *metzudat Tzion* commentary, and you'll see that he refers back to the verse in Devarim! So, I'm convinced that it has this "extended" meaning that I mentioned. Likewise in the viduy, I think "sararnu" means specifically, we have gone astray from your mitzvot. The term "sarnu mimitzvotecha" in the par. after *Ashamnu* means the same thing but in more words, as I see it.

Comment: שריך סוררים is translated here as rebellious http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1001.htm#23